# Can someone give me the default launch.json in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ok, so I was writing some simple python code and when I ran it, It always said attached to chrome.

So to fix this problem,I went into the launch.json and accidentally removed all the code.

Can you please give me the DEFAULT launch.json please?

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```